# auto-complete-mode not working

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I just followed [this site](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Installation_Script) to install auto-complete on Emacs. I installed it with "M-x load-file RETURN ~/path/to/etc/install.el".

The output of my installation was: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6184523/

After that, I added the recommended code to my ~/.emacs file and restarted Emacs. Typing "M-x auto-complete-mode" says "No match". I also tried to fix it by replacing flet with c-flet etc. but it hasn't changed anything too.

Version: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.8.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs has a package manager now. So just install the package from the list and you're done.
Here's the configuration that adds the two most popular repositories:

```
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list
 'package-archives
 '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list
 'package-archives
 '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

After this, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-list-packages`. The rest is pretty intuitive.

### UPD: A simple `auto-complete` setup for C++

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
      (lambda()
            (semantic-mode 1)
            (define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-z") 'c++-auto-complete)))

(defun c++-auto-complete ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((ac-sources
         `(ac-source-semantic
           ,@ac-sources)))
  (auto-complete)))
```

Comment: Pretty nice package manager. But I can't find auto-complete-mode there.

Comment: It's called `auto-complete` in there.

Comment: I checked again with auto-complete, but Emacs can't find anything

Comment: I also tried this: M-x package-install auto-complete = no match

Comment: Scroll to the end of the package buffer. How many packages you see? I have 2053.
If you have less, you didn't evaluate the code that I wrote above. Also use `g` to update.

Comment: I think Emacs didn't load something at the first time.. Now after restarting it shows all the packages. I also installed auto-complete. But for some reason nothing shows up when I type std:: in a .cpp file (<iostream> is included & auto-complete-mode is enabled).

Comment: That's because you need an `ac-source` for C++. You can get one either from `CEDET`
or from `auto-complete-clang-async`. I'm using CEDET. You can see my C++ setup at https://github.com/abo-abo/function-args.

Comment: Is it normal that auto-complete shows everything even if it's not in that namespace / class?

Comment: Yes. It comes from the fact the C++ is hard to parse.

Comment: Is there no way to fix this?

Comment: There's two ways: either a bulletproof C++ parser (doesn't exist even for eclipse),
or a bunch of personal hacks.

Comment: There is also a clang-based autocomplete for Emacs: http://truongtx.me/2013/03/06/emacs-ccpp-autocomplete-with-clang/

Comment: I've mentioned it above. I've tried it, but I'm not a big fan of clang. CEDET does its job well enough.

Comment: But why does CEDET work better here: http://cedet.sourceforge.net/intellisense.shtml

Comment: That's class member completion. CEDET does it quite well.
Call `semantic-ia-complete-symbol` and you'll get the same.

Comment: Yes it works. But how to call up a "graphical" menu which shows all possible methods, variables etc.

Comment: I've never had a need for that. But there's something called speedbar. Maybe that's what you want.

Comment: It's good too, but I am searching for this http://s21.postimg.org/ui6eu5nl3/complete.jpg. Only that this only shows everything I wrote.

Comment: error: Symbol's value as variable is void: ac-source-semantic

Comment: Call `(ac-config-default)`.

Comment: ac-config-default definition is also void

Comment: (require 'auto-complete-config)

Answer (score 0):

I tried some solutions that worked for other people, but it didn't quite work out.

Try setting the environment variable(s) to `~/emacs.d/` in both `.profile` and `.bashrc`
If that doesn't work out, try exporting the environment variable(s) with `su root` (won't work with `sudo`).

At least that worked for me while trying to install auto-complete-mode with golangs auto-complete-mode